# Access object in script from duo built js

Tags: javascript, duo.js

I am using duo.js but would like to expose an object so that it can be accessed in other parts in my html file.

In my index.js file I have;

```
var uuid = require('gjohnson/uuid');
var bind = require('ianstormtaylor/bind');
function User(options){
  this.protocol = window.location.protocol;
  this.options(options);
}
User.prototype.randomID = function(){
  return uuid();
};

module.exports = bind.all(new User());
var user = module.exports.User = User;
```

I run `duo index.js` to create the `build/index.js` file.

I then want to be able to access to `user` object in the script in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="build/index.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {
    console.log(user.randomID());
})();
</script>
```

But I get `ReferenceError: user is not defined'. I'm still learning about duo and am not familiar with the structure. How do I correctly expose the user object so that it can be accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Duo does **not** expose the scripts it builds to the global context. As such, you don't use inline scripts but instead build the script with Duo and serve it externally.

The script you currently have as your `index.js` should probably be something like `lib/user.js`. Then, the real `index.js` should be where you put your page's logic, such as the `user.randomID();`.

If you want to make the development process easier, consider using a tool like [duo-serve](http://github.com/dominicbarnes/duo-serve), which handles automatically rebuilding your scripts on each refresh.

To expose your built module to the `window` object, use the `--global` CLI flag. If you need to expose your module in a fashion more consumable by other package managers, use `--standalone` which outputs your script with a UMD.

Comment: Thanks @dominic-barnes. I've been ready through the Segment.io/analytics.js and learning a lot about their implementation of Duo. How did they manage to expose the `analytics` object?

Comment: Duo does have the `--global` CLI flag, where you can export the module you're building as a global value. (See [docs](https://github.com/duojs/duo/blob/master/docs/cli.md#usage))

Comment: Btw, [here](https://github.com/segmentio/analytics.js/blob/master/Makefile#L71) is the `Makefile` for segmentio/analytics.js. They're using the `--standalone` flag, which exports the library via UMD. (so other package managers can consume it) But if you just need to export to the global scope, you can just use `--global`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. If you update your response i'll mark it as the answer :) Thanks